# Spring WebClient to send Flux to ElasticSearch using /_bulk api

Tags: java, elasticsearch, flux, spring-webclient

What I would like to achieve:

- Use Spring WebClient to send a **Flux** to ElasticSearch leveraging the `/_bulk` api.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html

What I have tried:

Using this code:

```
public class BulkInsertOfFluxUsingWebClientBulkRestApi {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        WebClient client = WebClient.create("http://127.0.0.1:9200/").mutate().clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(HttpClient.create().wiretap(true))).build();
        Flux<String> createCommandFlux = Flux.interval(Duration.ofMillis(100))
                .map(i -> {
                    try {
                        Foo onePojo = new Foo(LocalDateTime.now().toString(), String.valueOf(i));
                        String jsonStringOfOnePojo = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(onePojo);
                        String bulkCreateCommande = "{ \"create\" : {} }\n" + jsonStringOfOnePojo + "\n";
                        return bulkCreateCommande;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        return "";
                    }
                });
        
        Disposable disposable = createCommandFlux
                .window(100) 
                .flatMap(windowFlux -> client
                        .post()
                        .uri("my_index/_bulk")
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_NDJSON)
                        .body(windowFlux, Foo.class)
                        .exchange()
                        .doOnNext(response -> System.out.println(response))
                        .flatMap(clientResponse -> clientResponse.bodyToMono(String.class)))
                .subscribe();
        Thread.sleep(1000000);
        disposable.dispose();
    }
```

Note:

- This is just using reactive Spring WebClient, not another http client, not the ElsaticSearch java client etc.
- It is trying to save a Flux (which can be infinite) inside ElasticSearch
- I would like to avoid making one http request per object, therefore, "grouping" them and sending them as bulk leveraging the `/_bulk` api.

Issue:

Unfortunately, this code is currently returning http 400 bad request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
    @Bean
    WebClient elasticWebClient() {
        return WebClient.builder()
                .baseUrl("http://localhost:9200")
                .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .build();
    }


  @Autowired ObjectMapper mapper;
    @GetMapping("write")
    Mono<Map> write() throws IOException {

        Function<Object, String> mapToString = new Function<Object, String>() {
            @Override
            public String apply(Object o) {
                try {
                    return mapper.writeValueAsString(o);
                } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        };

        final Map<String, Map<String, String>> headingJson = Map.of("index", Map.of("_index", "new_index"));
        final Map<String, String> value1 = Map.of("name", "name1", "description", "description1");
        final Map<String, String> value2 = Map.of("name", "name2", "description", "description2");
        final Map<String, String> value3 = Map.of("name", "name3", "description", "description3");
        final Map<String, String> value4 = Map.of("name", "name4", "description", "description4");
        final Map<String, String> value5 = Map.of("name", "name5", "description", "description5");
        final Map<String, String> value6 = Map.of("name", "name6", "description", "description6");

        final String requestBody = Stream.of(value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6)
                .flatMap(val -> Stream.of(headingJson, val))
                .map(mapToString)
                .collect(Collectors.joining("\n", "", "\n"));


        return client
                .post()
                .uri(u -> u.path("_bulk").build())
                .bodyValue(requestBody)
                .exchangeToMono(clientResponse -> clientResponse.toEntity(Map.class))
                .map(HttpEntity::getBody);
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using webclient I assume you also use spring so

Checkout spring api for reactive elastic search operations:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.reactive.operations

And use Reactive Elasticsearch template: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/4.2.0-M3/api/index.html?org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/ReactiveElasticsearchTemplate.html

```
protected reactor.core.publisher.Flux<org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkItemResponse> doBulkOperation(List<?> queries,
                                                                                                  BulkOptions bulkOptions,
                                                                                                  IndexCoordinates index)
```

here is example

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@Import(ReactiveElasticsearchRestClientAutoConfiguration.class)
public class ElasticDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ElasticDemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    ReactiveElasticsearchTemplate template(@Autowired ReactiveElasticsearchClient client) {
        return new ReactiveElasticsearchTemplate(client);
    }

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext context;

    @GetMapping
    Mono<String> triggerBulk() {


        final ArrayList<UpdateQuery> es = new ArrayList<>();

        es.add(UpdateQuery.builder(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .withDocument(Document.create().append("key1", "val1")).build());
        es.add(UpdateQuery.builder(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .withDocument(Document.create().append("key2", "val2")).build());
        es.add(UpdateQuery.builder(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .withDocument(Document.create().append("key3", "val3")).build());
        es.add(UpdateQuery.builder(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .withDocument(Document.create().append("key4", "val4")).build());


        return context.getBean(ReactiveElasticsearchTemplate.class)
                .bulkUpdate(es, IndexCoordinates.of("myIndex"))
                .map(x -> "OK");
    }
}
```

```
spring.elasticsearch.uris=https://localhost:9200
spring.elasticsearch.username=<user>
spring.elasticsearch.password=<pass>
```

Comment: Many thanks for the clear writing. The underlying ReactiveElasticsearchTemplate uses apache http client for the actual http requests. I would like to use webclient only, and also avoid an extra dependency. Would you have an example with Webclient only for the bulk? I will award the bounty if you have. In the meanwhile, upvote as it is a clear answer.

Comment: starting from spring boot 3.x.x they only support webclient and highlevel client is deprecated 
so it is not a problem if you use spring boot 3+
but notice that it use new java client v8+ and could get data only from elasticsearch 8+
in my set up I use spring boot 3.0.5, java 17, and spring boot starter elasticsearch that has transitive dependency org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-client:8.5.3

I think this one uses what you need org.springframework.data:spring-data-elasticsearch:5.0.4

Comment: But I recommend to check docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.clients.reactive

Comment: agreed @Oleg, it is not that we haven't checked on spring data elastic. As you said, the whole stack needs to be bumped up (which we are not ready yet). Furthermore, that would require to bring an entire dependency, while you can see the request only takes couple of lines. We just want to leverage elastic _bulk rest endpoint and construct the http request manually. If you that have handy, that would be great

Comment: what version of elastic (docker image version) do you use ?

Comment: If you need lightweight solution u could send data into elastic directly using webclient:
POST /<target>/_doc/
Index One: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html
Index Bulk: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html -> this is exactly what I am trying to use (please see original post with webflux request), but not working, hence the stack overflow post. I tried with Elastic from version 7.6 all the way to 8.7

Answer (score 0):

Here is how your payload should looks like when send request to bulk api

[image]

Comment: Yes, agreed, and if you look at my ```.body(windowFlux, Foo.class)``` and ```bulkCreateCommande```, it is the same. Yet, I am getting a 400 bad request. Would you know why? Do you have a working sample please?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with

```
String bulkCreateCommande = "{ \"create\" : {} }\n" + jsonStringOfOnePojo + "\n";
```

Its missing the `_index` parameter.

If you could share a reference of what is working for you via curl or Postman tool, I think it would be helpful to debug since that's basically what you are trying to achieve via code.

Comment: agreed @Bibek, I also thought of that. But you can see in my sample ```.uri("my_index/_bulk")``` the index is within the uri. As per the doc and tested with Postman, having the index there is valid.